# AWS Availability Zone Errors

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I am trying to implement an availability zone in AWS using Terraform. I have tried using the following:

```
data "aws_availability_zones" "available_zones" {
  state = "available"
}

#Create subnets in the first two available availability zones

resource "aws_subnet" "primary" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[0]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
}

resource "aws_subnet" "secondary" {
  availability_zone = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names[1]
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.main_vpc.id
}
```

However, when I do this and run my terraform plan command, I end up with the following error:

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on autoscaling.tf line 20, in resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "auto_scaling_group":
   20: availability_zones        =  data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones 
     |------
     | data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones is object with 10 attributes
```

This is the example provided by the Hashicorp Registry docs. Any suggestions on how to rectify this issue? Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: The error is not consistent with the code it seems. It looks like you have changed the code after you got the error.

Comment: Where is that example you are referring to? https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/availability_zones lists `.names` or `.zone_ids` as the correct thing to use to actually get the zone details.

Comment: Ah, ok, so you are not using any attribute references in the autoscaling group resource, so it should be `availability_zones = data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones.names`.

Comment: When you shared the error message you missed the last paragraph of the message which explains what type of value this argument was expecting. I expect it's telling you that this argument is expecting a list or set of strings, whereas you've provided an object instead. It would help if you would include the full error message.

Comment: When I modify the names variable with availability zones, now I get the following: 

│ Error: Value for unconfigurable attribute
│ 
│   with data.aws_availability_zones.available_zones,
│   on main.tf line 146, in data "aws_availability_zones" "available_zones":
│  146:   names = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
│ 
│ Can't configure a value for "names": its value will be decided automatically based on the result of applying this configuration.

Comment: Can you please paste the rest of the code? the error message complains about "aws_autoscaling_group", the code you posted has no aws_autoscaling_group definition.